# how to check if iommu is enabled?

Tags: linux, centos, iommu

I have a centos 7.2 linux installed. I want to check if IOMMU is enabled in the system or not. How can i figure it out? Is there any /proc or /sys entry i can check to make sure is it enabled or not?

Comment: Opening UEFI ("BIOS") settings is easier and faster.

Comment: check the `kern.log[.*]` files for mentions of `Adding to iommu group ....` etc